# What does Test t = new Test(); is trying to do in Class?

Tags: java

What does the `Test t = new Test();` is trying to do in this class?

```java
public class Test

{

    static int x = 11;
    private int y = 33;
    public void method1(int x)
    {
        **Test t = new Test();**
        this.x = 22;
        y = 44;
 
        System.out.println("Test.x: " + Test.x);
        System.out.println("t.x: " + t.x);
        System.out.println("t.y: " + t.y);
        System.out.println("y: " + y);
    }
 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.method1(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: It instantiates an object of type `Test`, and assigns a reference to that object to variable `t`.  It's also a constructor call.  If you don't know what that means, you need to read up more on the Java programming language.

Comment: See [Java Tutorial - Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test t = new Test();
```

This code creates an object from the Test class. The purpose of this code is to show how we can access global and local variables.

Code output

```
Test.x: 22
t.x: 22
t.y: 33
y: 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not particularly clear/looks incomplete. `this` is a keyword to refer to the object/class whos method is being invoked.

T is an instance of class Test. But where is the definition of class Test?

The code you're referring to is simply creating (constructing) an object named T of class Test.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new object of type `TEST` and its reference is assigned to `t`